# Close css hover dropdown menu after item click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a classic menu bar on a web page using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Everything works, but clicking on the menu item does not hide the menu. Rather, the menu appears until the cursor moves off the item. This is unnatural, and is particularly troublesome on touch based devices. The solutions online all use jQuery, which looks unfamiliar and alien to me. Is there a way to hide the menu without using jQuery?

```
function onButtonClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(event.target.id);
  //close menu here
}
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crlab/uq6at5mk/

Answer (score 2):

First, you specify the element to deal with:

```
var el = this.parentNode;
```

Then, using the same logic you did on CSS, you set `display` to `none`.

```
el.style.display = "none";
```

Finally, after `30ms`, you restore the inline style to preserve `hover` effect:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.removeProperty("display");
}, 30);
```

The final result would be like this:

```
function onButtonClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(event.target.id);

  var el = this.parentNode;
  el.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.removeProperty("display");
  }, 30);

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why setTimeout could you please explain?

Comment: Because it requires some delay enough to hide the menu properly based on browser repainting. Otherwise it will remain open. Try to run it without setTimeout to check it out.

Comment: @Azametzin - Your solution works for Chrome and Firefox, but it does not work for Safari (tested on both MacOS and iOS).

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach by handling click event:

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown" id="file" onclick="onClick(this)">
    ...
</li>
<li class="dropdown"  id="view" onclick="onClick(this)">
...
</li>
```

CSS:

```
/*.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}*/
```

And JavaScript:

```
function onClick(event) {
    let list = event.children;
    setDisplayProperty(list);
}

function setDisplayProperty(list) {
    for (let item of list) {
        console.log(item.id);
        if(item.style.display == 'block')
            item.style.display = '';
        else
            item.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```